# Difficulty deciding which t-test is best for this particular problem

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics, psychology

I have a problem which I am having a great deal of trouble deciding which t-test is best. For starters I am using JASP.  The problem consist of deciding whether attractive people have more daughters or sons, it consist of 274 names and the number of sons and number of daughters.  Now I know It will be a t-test but I am unsure if it will be independent, paired, or one sample t-test.  My instructions are as follows "Be sure to do test your assumption of normality, calculate an effect size, get descriptive statistics, and a descriptive plot with a 95% confidence interval.".
Thanks in advance for any help 
Daniel

Comment: I don't see how comparing two proportions should be a t test. Seems like this is an assignment in which case you would need to add the self-study tag.

Comment: What do you understand are the reasons for using the different types of t-test? (Have you searched this site or just used a web search?). Which particular points are preventing you from reaching a decision? I assume that the names are also associated with an "attractiveness" category?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Stats 101 homework questions are often pretty bad, but this is truly bizarre.

Comment: essentially my instructions are to do test your assumption of normality, calculate an effect size, get descriptive statistics, and a descriptive plot with a 95% confidence interval.  Once I enter the info into JASP there is multiple options for a t test, My professor has made it clear he wants us to use a t-test, bu I am unsure if this is an Independent t-test, a paired t-test, or a one sample t-test

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be an assignment I will give you some advice that might help.

When I was starting with these kind of tasks I always made myself an overview.:

**IV**

Attractiveness rating: $X_r \in [0,10]$

*or*

Attractive: Yes: = 1, No := 0 (categorical) $X \{0,1\}$

**DV**

Number of daughters: $Y_1 \in \mathbb{N}$

Number of sons: $Y_2 \in \mathbb{N}$

*or*

Difference in children (how many more sons): $Y_d \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then clarify what your **hypothesis** really is:

$H_0: Y_{1, attractive} = Y_{1, not attractive}$

$H_A: Y_{1, attractive} \neq Y_{1, not attractive}$

*or*

$H_0: Y_{1, attractive} = Y_{2, attractive}$

$H_A: Y_{1, attractive} \neq Y_{2, attractive}$

*or*

$Y_d=a+b*X_r + \epsilon$

$H_0: b = 0$

$H_A: b > 0$

This way you a) get a great overview and b) it is easier for others to help you.

If this hint is insufficient please leave comment below I will help you further.

Edit: If you put all your thoughts in such a scheme, the appropriate t test should become apparent to you :) If not, leave a comment

Edit:

You can test in different ways. You could for example ask yourself for every attractive parent how many more or less daughters or sons do they have?  Then ask the same again for unattractive parents. Therefore you would test within each parent (*within* is equivalent to *paired*). Another idea would be to test who gets more sons,  attractive or unattractive parents. Then the same for daughters (*between* two groups is equivalent to *two sample*). Further, you might ask yourself if attractive parents got proportionally more or less daughters than you might expect (daughters 51.3% if I am not mistaken)  then you do the same for unattractive parents (twice compare one group against a reference value is equivalent to twice use a *one sample test*)

Do you see that there are tons of different ways to apply t test. It took me a while to come up with the last option because I find it extremely idiotic. Yet,  it is possible.
You have to choose which one is closest to the precise question you want to answer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  While we are allowed to use the Program JASP to do the math itself for us, I am still struggling with if this example would be considered a paired t-test, an independent t-test, or a one sample t-test.

Comment: Do you understand all the symbols? If not I will try proper English ;)

Comment: Unfortunately math and especially statistics is not my strong suit.  If you wouldn't mind I do appreciate the help

Comment: Check my updated answer